# Calculate Decrease of count in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I am looking for an option in Prometheus to give me the opposite of increase(). I can see increase(), change(), delta() but none of them specifically mentions reduction in count over time. I have used increase many times for checking if number of errors have increased over a period of time:

increase(http_request_failure[5m]) > 5

Now, for an alerting purpose I need to find if a specific count has reduced over a period of time. It turns out there is no decrease function. How do I find out a change in negative direction? Of a metric's count that has reduced by some amount over 5 minutes?

Thanks,
Arnav

Comment: Would a negative value work? I.e. -5?

Comment: By definition, a counter is always increasing except when it is reset to 0. You must be referring to decrease of rate.

Comment: I added a check for a -ve value by using delta. It's working as of now.

Comment: I had the same issue and ended up using `clamp_max(delta(metric{}), 0)` to get only negative values.

Answer (score 1):

I have other metrics requirements, however, the principle and function are the same and can be applied to any other queues under monitoring.
My case here is to notify a queue owner in case the queue has more than 1000 unconsumed messages and is not decreasing within 1h:

```
sum by (queue) (min_over_time(messages_ready[1h]) >= 1000) and delta(messages_ready[1h])>=0)
```

It works well for me.